# how to calculate time in php logical

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
if(count($pay)): 
  $days=0;
  foreach ($pay as $pays):
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $today = time();
    $cdate = strtotime($pays->times);//strtotime('2011-09-27');//strtotime($row_details['payment_date']);// testing
    $dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    $dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days 
    $day=$dayscalculate.(($dayscalculate == 1) ? " day" : " days"); 
    $days +=$day;
  endforeach;

endif; ?>
Your Service Remaining Time
<?php if($days<4){?>
   <span class="label label-danger label-as-badge"><?php echo $days.  (($days == 1) ? " day" : " days");?></span>
<?}else{?>
   <span class=" label label-success label-as-badge"><?php echo $days.(($days == 1) ? " day" : " days");?></span>
<?}
```

Suppose i have five dates in my database field like user payment 1 jan 2016 , and 30 jan 2016 and user pay again 28 feb 2016 and again user pay 30 march 2016  and again pay 31 march 2016 .

above code working when user pay monthly basis problem is this when user pay two payment in same month then like 30march and 31 march then there there days difference  decreased two days (-2)  every day there membership valid for  next two month but now there membership days end in one month because my code not working.

i have no idea how to calculate days.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's hard to read. Btw, no need to keep closing and reopening the PHP-tags (`<?php` and `?>`). It also makes it hard to read. Unless you have any HTML in between, open it once and close it in the end.

Comment: `<?php echo days; ?>`

Comment: update code.. please check